# TexnicCentre creates additional files

Tags: pdftex

I am using TexnicCentre 2.02 64bit (stable version). When I build a latex file (Latex => PDF mode), it creates a lot of additional files (AUX, TOC, BBL, etc.) and clutters my directory. Is there a way to create only the latex source and the pdf files ? It is a bit of a pain to delete the extra files manually every time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: These files are used by LaTeX to build the .pdf. You can have them grouped in a subdirectory if you compile with the `--aux-directory=…` switch.

Comment: most files are needed in the next compilation to get labels, table of contents and bibliography. So leave them in the directory.

Comment: If you remove the files at each run, you'll never get cross-references and citations right.